VirtualBox VM bridged network and issues connecting to “eduroam” Wi-Fi
I have an Ubuntu 22 computer on which I have a Windows 10 VM using VirtualBox. I use bridged network settings.
When I am at home on the Wi-Fi or using a personal hotspot from my smartphone, Windows 10 VM connects perfectly to the internet (Ethernet, network 3). However, when I connect to the university's eduroam Wi-Fi it does not connect to the eduroam network.
My guess is that is has something to do with the login credentials: on the Ubuntu computer I need to give my university credentials to connect to the eduroam Wi-Fi. It could also be some restrictive settings of the eduroam network that prevents me from connecting through bridged settings in my VM.
Open Wi-Fi networks like the guest network at my university, which does not require login credentials, result in the same problem. So I guess it's the restrictive settings or some kind of prevention for 'address spoofing' or something…

Is the VM able to get an IP address through DHCP? It's unlikely to be an eduroam-specific issue (after auth, the Wi-Fi frames are the same, and it leads to your university's network either way), but the way Wi-Fi 'bridging' is done, it can certainly trip up some protections.

@grawity_u1686 how would I check if the VM is able to get an IP address through DHCP?

Within the Windows VM, take a look at interface configuration (ipconfig /all or Get-NetIPAddress | ft or Settings>Network) just to see if it has an IP address – or on the Ubuntu host, fire up Wireshark and watch for DHCP discover/offer/request/ack packets as the VM boots.
